# how to post a photo from android to the cloud and grab its url alter?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, api, android-intent

I want to write an android app that post a photos to any cloud sotrage service (free)

and then saves its published url in local DB.

Is there any API that allows this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android) for a simple app that uploads a photo to Google Drive.

Comment: it gets the url later?

Comment: other providers as well?

Comment: you asked to upload photo to any cloud storage service - Google Drive is one of them.

Comment: I wanted the user to be able to choose